# How to disable a 'Done' button from nav bar when keyboard slides in?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.2

I believe I can't disable it because I can't access that `UIBarButttonItem` programmatically
(with either viewWithTag or `rightBarButtonItem`).

Any suggestions  (short from adding the interface without IB)?
As a test, I also tried adding a button programmatically (on the left of the nav bar), but it did not display in the nav bar.

RELEVANT CODE (In `MyEditorViewControler.m`):

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender { //successfully executes when keyboard slides in

        UINavigationItem *item = self.navigationItem; //item  = 0x6420e0  OK.  (value at debugger breakpoints)
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton4    = (UIBarButtonItem *) [self.view viewWithTag:44]; //doneButton4 = 0x0,  not OK.
        doneButton4.enabled = NO; 
    }
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)sender {  //successfully executes when keyboard  slides out.  
        ...
        UIButton* doneButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:44]; //Attempt to re-enable button.
        doneButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad {   //Attempt to programmatically add a *left* button to the nav bar. Result: Button does not display in nav bar.
        .... 
        UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
        [leftBarButtonItem release];
    }
```

DETAILS
        I would think this is a common case because that Done button:
            a) is a `UIBarButttonItem` added from IB Library to navigation bar that is in a Scroll View that has some `UITextField's`.
            b) behaves as expected  (to save the user-entered data etc),
except for not getting disabled when keyboard appears.
            c) IB > Inspector > Bar Button Item Attributes shows:
    Identifier  = Done
    Tag         = 44
    Class       = `UIBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to a notification (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`) posted when the keyboard slides in:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then implement `-keyboardWillShow:`.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow {
    UIButton *button = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    button.enabled = NO;
}
```

To reenable the button again, do the same for the `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

Comment: With keyboardWillShow  I have access to the leftBarButtonItem (great), but that button (created programmatically in viewDidLoad)                      does not display in the nav bar (created in IB).                     So I can't tell if it was disabled or not. How get  that leftBarButtonItem to display?

Comment: SOLUTION: Many thanks for you responses. It works now.  The trick was, instead of grabbing the button directly,  to grab the nab bar first then grab the button from that.  
UINavigationBar *navBar = (UINavigationBar *)[self.view viewWithTag:22];  
then enable and disable in the textFieldDidBeginEditing textFieldDidEndEditing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be using

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem; 
doneButton.enabled = YES;

//Both of these should work, you shouldn't need any type of IBOutlets for this

UINavigationItem *item = self.navigationItem;
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = item.leftBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed that, but that is not the main issue.                In code above, the question is either:              1) how get the test leftBarButtonItem to display first (and later enable/disable it) OR                 2) how get the IB button (not classified as left or right) to disable (once that is done, is should be trivial to enable).

Comment: Yes, I have not added anything (Outlets or properties) to .h for this.